# Avoid running GeoIP on every page

Tags: python, session, cookies, nginx, geoip

This is the module I am working with: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGeoipModule

From what I can see, since it is configured on the nginx config and uwsgi it looks like there is no choice but to have it run the geoip on every page and then only collect and use the variable when needed.

From a performance point of view I would rather have it so I request the geoip ONLY when needed, cache it in a cookie or session and then not request it again to speed up the site.

Is anyone able to tell me if this is possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> From a performance point of view I would rather have it so I request the geoip ONLY when needed, cache it in a cookie or session and then not request it again to speed up the site.
>   Is anyone able to tell me if this is possible?`

Yes, it's possible. But from a performance point of view, you should not worry, as geoip database are stored in memory (at the reading configuration phase) and nginx doing lookups very fast.

Anyway if you want, you can use something like:

```
set $country $cookie_country;

if ($country == '') {
    set $country $geoip_country_code;
    add_header Set-Cookie country=$geoip_country_code; 
}

uwsgi_param GEOIP_COUNTRY $country;
```

Answer (score -2):

No, you can't make nginx to perform GeoIP lookup on demand only. Since you define a **geoip_country** or **geoip_city** directive, nginx will request data from GeoIP database, whether the answer is used later or not. But you can fetch GeoIP data without nginx at all, i.e. directly with your application. Take a look for python geoip lib: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/downloadable#Python-5

Comment: You're completely wrong. Variables in Nginx are evaluated only on demand. If `$geoip_*` variable was not used during the request processing, then geoip db was not lookuped.

Comment: So, if I dont call the geoip variable on my page the geoip module wont be executed at all? I'm concerned about page loads so on more pages i wont be calling it so I want to know it wont be loaded or slow down the page.

Comment: *So, if I dont call the geoip variable on my page the geoip module wont be executed at all?* Yes, exactly.

Comment: You are welcome. =) Actually, a lot of interesting information about nginx is in the official mailing lists: http://mailman.nginx.org/mailman/listinfo